# When a utility company uses the term "installed capacity" does it mean energy or power?

Tags: power, energy

This is directly from this [website](http://www.ieso.ca/learn/ontario-supply-mix/ontario-energy-capacity): "The current installed capacity on Ontario’s transmission grid is more than 36,800 MW". Does it mean total energy generated & transmitted in a year OR the grid's capacity to transmit this much electricity in a second?

Also, can I compare this number with the energy generated by 1 litre of biofuel (which is 9 KWH)? i.e. do I need to multiply 36,800 by 3600 (minutes*seconds) to ensure I'm comparing in the same dimensions?

Comment: I think that means the sum of each installation's "[nameplate capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nameplate_capacity)". Whether or not all of that capacity is in use at any particular time is a different matter (and probably never actually happens, in practice.) There is another term, "capacity factor," that relates the actual capacity in use at any particular time. That factor should almost always be less than 1.

Comment: Megawatts are a unit of power.

Comment: As @τεκ points out, there is a difference between energy and power (energy is power times time.) Liters of fuel are "energy" and not "power." To convert average power to energy, multiply by the time period. To convert energy to average power, divide the energy by the time over which it is used. Even then, energy is measured in calories, Joules, Newton-meters, watt-hours, watt-seconds, and depending on assumptions implied in the conversation, (water behind a dam), bizarre things like hectare-meters.

Comment: The annual energy consumption of Ontario for 2014 was 140 TWh.

Comment: @τεκ. Megawatts are a unit of power, but for power plants this could be interpreted as Mega-Joules, as opposed to peak power for short demand.

Comment: If you could detonate the biofuel in 1 us the  1 litre of biofuel (which is 9 KWH*3600=32.4kJ) would yield 32Gigawatts

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Can you post up the schematic for that? ;) I may be able to find a use for it. :)

Comment: @τεκ - After seeing your comment I realized that I was looking under the wrong hood, barking up the wrong tree, etc. This link has the energy generated info: http://www.ieso.ca/corporate-ieso/media/year-end-data

Answer (score 3):

Megawatts is a unit of power not energy.  What the utility is telling you is that they have enough electric generators on hand to generate up to 36,800 megawatts of power at one time. You need to multiply time by power to get energy.  However since this maximum capacity will almost never be used at one time, it is somewhat meaningless to use this number for energy calculations.

Comment: It is also kind of idealized in that at any given time, some generators may be unavailable due to maintenance. I am kind of assuming, since I don't work in that field.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in the thread, I realized I should look at total energy generated. This link has the info I was looking for: http://www.ieso.ca/corporate-ieso/media/year-end-data

Comment: You have posted this as an answer rather than as an update to your question. If it is the answer you were looking for then you can "accept" it to indicate that your problem has been solved.